# iOS injecting redirect using javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to redirect using iOS's stringByEvaluatingJavavascriptFromString. The whole app is basically just our mobile site with an objectice C wrapper.

Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)sendToCart:(id)sender
{
    self.action = @"cart";
    self.addingToList = NO;
    self.selectedIndex = 3;

    if([self.barCodeArray count] > 0)
    {
        NSString *myUrl = @"http://mycompany'surl/barcodeAddTo.ep?action=cart&barcodes=";

        NSMutableArray *newQuantityArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.arrayIndex];

        for(NSInteger i = 0; i <= self.arrayIndex; i++)
        {
            if ([self.quantityArray objectAtIndex:i] != NULL)
            {
                [newQuantityArray addObject:[self.quantityArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }

        NSDictionary *barCodeAndQuantityData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: self.barCodeArray, @"barcodes", newQuantityArray, @"qty", nil];

        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:barCodeAndQuantityData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSString *myDictionaryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        myUrl = [myUrl stringByAppendingString:myDictionaryString];

        NSString *newUrl = [myUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"jq('body').append('<a id=\"submitToCart\"></a>\');"];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"jq('#submitToCart').on('click', function(){window.location.href = %@});", newUrl ]];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"jq('#submitToCart').trigger('click');"];

        NSLog(@"Your encoded url looks like %@", newUrl);

        /*
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[myUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSLog(@"Your url looks like %@", url);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        //NSLog(@"Your request looks like %@", request);

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
         */
        [self hideScanViewElementsShowWebView];

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Bar Codes Scanned" message:@"You haven't scanned any bar codes" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        alert = nil;
    }
 }
```

What I'm trying to do in these 3 lines of code, is this possible?

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"jq('body').append('<a id=\"submitToCart\"></a>\');"];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"jq('#submitToCart').on('click', function(){window.location.href = %@});", newUrl ]];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"jq('#submitToCart').trigger('click');"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview

Just inject redirect function to your webview and then call it.

Comment: Yup, that'll do it. Thanks!